# Delphi ISAPI dll module on iis - HTTPS

Tags: iis, soap, https, isapi

I have created a Delphi SOAP API project,  and have deployed the ISAPI dll on IIS, it is called using HTTP now, and works good.
But i now need to deploy this dll on IIS to be called with Https request, (certified).

What are the necessary changes that need to be done on IIS or any windows feature etc... to deploy ISAPI on https site and make any test app successfully call it.

Comment: There is no difference for ISAPI as such modules only process the requests which are already decrypted once received. If you want to check whether HTTPS is enabled, there are several server variables.

Comment: Can you help me more please? So you are saying that the way of writing my service is the same?what should be done to enable HTTPS?

Comment: Add an HTTPS binding to your web site on IIS and that should be enough. It is an IIS side setting.

Comment: I added a self certificate and enabled the SSL, but when i brows to the WSDL dll, and try to run it, it is not getting an https://... link, instead it is tiring to access the http:// ... link